# Error 535 - sending SMTP Email to SendGrid using Telnet

Tags: testing, sendgrid, telnet

I'm trying to send an SMTP Email to SendGrid using Telnet and getting "535 Authentication failed: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked" as a response when I enter my base64 encoded API Key.

I have authenticated my domain.
I have a Full Access SendGrid API Key (and converted it to base64).

I have created and verified a sender (**but**, it has a mere ...@gmail.com address).

I am following the steps at https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/getting-started-smtp.
I have tried port 25 and port 587, but I can't get beyond step 4: Enter your Base64 converted API Key.

What could be causing this error?
Do I need to create a sender with a business email address?
Do I need a paid SendGrid plan?

Comment: How are you base 64 encoding your API key? If you [decode you encoded API key](https://www.base64decode.org/) do you get the original API key? Are you using the base 64 encoded version of the text "apikey", `YXBpa2V5`, as the username?

Comment: Hi philnash, I used echo in Terminal (Preview) on Windows 10 piped through OpenSSL. Thanks, I’ll try decode and check against original key. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @philnash,
So, using Windows Terminal, I enter 
echo '<my api key here>' | openssl base64 -A | openssl base64 -d
and get my api key back, as expected.

Then, I enter
echo '<my api key here>' | openssl base64 -A
and I get the base64 encoded value that I use in Telnet.

However, In Telnet I'm still getting the following error
535 Authentication failed: The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, or revoked.

Any suggestions appreciated?

Comment: @philnash, Yes I am using the base 64 encoded version of the text "apikey", YXBpa2V5, as the username.

Comment: Ok, you say you've both authenticated a domain, and verified a gmail address. Which are you using as the `From` address here? If you're using the gmail address, can you try with any email address from the authenticated domain?